# conversion of json object to java list object

Tags: java, json

my object is

```
    String obj = " {\"userNames\":[\"aaaaa aaaaa\",\"Anders Ohm\",\"Arthur Hansen\"]}";
```

Need to convert obj to java List object which contains the details of usernames with the elements 
"aaaaa aaaaa","Anders Ohm","Arthur Hansen"

Comment: So?  Deserialize to a Map, then ask for the "userNames" element of the Map.  That will be your List.

Comment: (Understand that all JSON has a direct translation to/from Maps and Lists, though the particular structure can vary infinitely.)

Comment: On a high level you can parse the string to a json object and then get usernames as a json array. Then go from there.

Comment: Great fleas have little fleas upon their backs to bite 'em,
And little fleas have lesser fleas, and so ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library for json processing.

Using the ObjectMapper, your JSON could be parsed like this:

```
class Data {
    List<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getUserNames() {
        return userNames;
    }

    public void setUserNames( List<String> userNames ) {
        this.userNames = userNames;
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    String obj = " {\"userNames\":[\"aaaaa aaaaa\",\"Anders Ohm\",\"Arthur Hansen\"]}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Data data = mapper.readValue( obj, Data.class );

    System.out.println(data.getUserNames());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create class

```
public class UserNames {


    private List<String> userNames;

    public  List<String> getUserNames() {
        return userNames;
    }

    public  void setUserNames(List<String> userNames) {
        this.userNames = userNames;
    }
}
```

Then parse it as

```
String obj = " {\"userNames\":[\"aaaaa aaaaa\",\"Anders Ohm\",\"Arthur Hansen\"]}";
        UserNames userNames =gson.fromJson(obj, UserNames.class);
        List<String> names = userNames.getUserNames();
```

You can download Google gson from here

[Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: JSONObject object = new JSONObject(" {\"userNames\":[\"aaaaa aaaaa\",\"Anders Ohm\",\"Arthur Hansen\"]}");
   JSONArray userNamesList = (JSONArray)object.get("userNames");
   
   ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<String>();     
   if (userNamesList != null) { 
      int len = userNamesList.length();
      for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
       userNames.add(userNamesList.get(i).toString());
      } 
   } 
   System.out.println(userNames);